# Include text in echoed hyperlink

Tags: php

I´d like to include an extra two words into an echoed hyperlink. I have no PHP knowledge so far. Could anyone put me in the right direction?

```
<p class="excerpt"><strong> Bekijk meer van <?php echo get_the_term_list ( $post->ID, 'store' , '' )   ?>
```

It gives Bekijk meer van **storename**. I want it to show something like Bekijk meer van **extra1 storename extra 2**.

Comment: <p class="excerpt"><strong> Bekijk meer van extra1 <?php echo get_the_term_list ( $post->ID, 'store' , '' )   ?> extra 2

Answer (score 2):

Never just print the result of `get_the_term_list()` without additional checks. It might return an instance of `WP_Error` which is an object, not a string.

Save the result of `get_the_term_list()` in a variable and print the terms only if there *are* terms and not an error:

```
<?php
$stores = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'store', '', ', ' );

// We got something back, and it is not an error.
if ( ! empty( $stores ) and ! is_wp_error( $stores ) )
{
    echo "<p class='excerpt'>
        <strong>Bekijk meer van extra1 $stores extra2</strong>
    </p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: 'Save the result of get_the_term_list() in a variable and print the terms only if there are terms ...' is not related to question and the rest is exactly what I commented above.

Comment: @revo Whenever possible we use a question to show how to do it better than the asker had it planned. And in its current form there is nothing WordPress specific in the question; I tried to show how it _could_ be a WordPress issue (`is_wp_error()`). And a comment is not an answer.

Comment: poor question doesn't need an answer except for receiving votes. That's the exact manner u did on my `better than the asker had it planned` answer on the other question.

Comment: @revo Agreed, it is not a good question. But the opportunity to point at the error that should not be printed is useful. No idea what other answer you are talking about. If you think a moderator did something wrong raise the issue on [meta] or flag it.

Comment: thanks for helping me. I cannot seem to figure out on how to implement it, as I have no PHP knowledge whatsoever. Could you please tell me what to replace for what?

Comment: @Ramonv Replace the entire line, starting with `<p class="excerpt">` with the PHP code.

Comment: I tried, however it's not working. There seems to be an error somewhere, as the site barely showing more than the header now.

Comment: @Ramonv Sorry, I had a typo in my cde. Please try again.

Comment: This is working:) But unfortunately still not got the other two words included in the url. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ramonv What URL?

Comment: http://trimbie.nl/ (it's a test site)

Comment: @toscho do you see any change for the code that would help?

Comment: @Ramonv I am not sure I understand you. If you want to change the term link you have to filter `term_link`. That's a completely different question. And please do not create new accounts; use one account only.